# Shifting selected months in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I am struggling to find a solution for the following problem: I have a dataframe which reports quarterly values. Unfortunately, some of the companies report their quarterly numbers a month after the typical release quarter-dates. For this reason, I would like to select these dates and change them to the typical release date. My dataframe looks like this:

```
# dataframe 1
rng1 = pd.date_range('2014-12-31', periods=5, freq='3M')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng1, 'Company': [1, 1, 1, 1 ,1], 'Val': np.random.randn(len(rng1)) }) 
# dataframe 2
rng2 = pd.date_range('2015-01-30', periods=5, freq='3M')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng2, 'Company': [2, 2, 2, 2 ,2],'Val': np.random.randn(len(rng2)) }) 

# Target Dataframe 
frames = [df1, df2]
df_fin = pd.concat(frames)

Output:
    Date       Company   Val
0   2014-12-31  1        0.374427
1   2015-03-31  1        0.328239
2   2015-06-30  1       -1.226196
3   2015-09-30  1       -0.153937
4   2015-12-31  1       -0.146096
0   2015-01-31  2        0.283528
1   2015-04-30  2        0.426100
2   2015-07-31  2       -0.044960
3   2015-10-31  2       -1.316574
4   2016-01-31  2        0.353073
```

So what I would like to do is the following: Company 2 reports their numbers a month later. For this reason I would like to change their dates so they allign with company 1. This means I would change dates such as the 2015-01-31 to the 2014-12-31.

Any help is highly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with direction `nearest` to merge the dataframe `df_in` with the reference quarterly dates `qDates`:

```
# Refrence quarterly dates (typical release dates)
qDates = pd.date_range('2014-12-31', periods=5, freq='Q')

df = pd.merge_asof(
    df_fin.sort_values(by='Date'), pd.Series(qDates, name='Quarter'),
    left_on='Date', right_on='Quarter', direction='nearest')

df = (
    df.sort_values(by=['Company', 'Quarter'])
    .drop('Date', 1)
    .rename(columns={'Quarter': 'Date'})
    .reindex(df_fin.columns, axis=1)
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

---

```
# print(df)
        Date  Company       Val
0 2014-12-31        1  0.146874
1 2015-03-31        1  0.297248
2 2015-06-30        1  1.444860
3 2015-09-30        1 -0.348871
4 2015-12-31        1 -0.093267
5 2014-12-31        2 -0.238166
6 2015-03-31        2 -1.503571
7 2015-06-30        2  0.791149
8 2015-09-30        2 -0.419414
9 2015-12-31        2 -0.598963
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks a lot. I managed to get a similar result with downsampling and then upsampling the data, but this approach is a lot nicer and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I get what you mean. You can use [`pd.DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) or [`pd.offsets.MonthOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthOffset.html) here, to add/minus number of month(s) to `Date` condition by column value `Company == 2`

For example:

`df_fin.loc[df_fin['Company'] == 2,'Date'] = df_fin.loc[df_fin['Company'] == 2,'Date'] - pd.DateOffset(months=1)`

`df_fin` prints:

```
# df_fin
    Date    Company Val
0   2014-12-31  1   -0.794092
1   2015-03-31  1   -2.632114
2   2015-06-30  1   -0.176383
3   2015-09-30  1   0.701986
4   2015-12-31  1   -0.447678
0   2014-12-31  2   -0.003322
1   2015-03-30  2   0.475669
2   2015-06-30  2   -1.024190
3   2015-09-30  2   1.241122
4   2015-12-31  2   0.096882
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solution works great for my example. Once you have more dataframes and don't know which ones are "shifted", @shubhamSharma 's solution come's in handy as well.